# Datatable not working correctly with boostrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, bootstrap-modal, responsive

I'm  trying to find my error while using `datatable` with bootstrap styling. I'm new to this, I followed steps mentioned on `datatables.net`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#upcTable').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

    "responsive": true
  });
});
```

```html
<table id="upcTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="margin-top: 30px;" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>SmallImageURL</th>
      <th>ASIN</th>
      <th>UPC</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>PackageQuantity</th>
      <th>PackageDimensions</th>
      <th>OfferListingCountNew</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>M1</th>
      <th>M2</th>
      <th>M3</th>
      <th>M4</th>
      <th>M5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>5421</td>
      <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>5421</td>
      <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
      <td>8422</td>
      <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>5421</td>
      <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/themeroller.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css">
```

I have included following Js

```
<script src="js/myscript.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I have two `datatable`, it's working fine with one table but not with the other. I have downloaded all JS and CSS file onto my local machine.
Here I have just given one `datatable`.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error it's just bootstrap styling not working

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5jwvdtbc/ Seems to be working fine from my end :)

Comment: I want something like this https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add all the required css and js for the outcome.

```
//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css
```

Is this what you are looking for..??
https://jsfiddle.net/kajalc/krdp5Lo9/

Comment: Nope, looking for this https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

Comment: Updated the fiddle. Please check again. Removed all the resources and added only those mentioned on the plugin styling example.

Comment: Hi, I have more than one datatable,it's working fine with one table but not with other. this is so weird it's working fine on fiddle, but not in my program https://jsfiddle.net/x4n5dqmy/

Comment: add the files through resources section on the left not in css section.

Answer (score 0):

I think the id of the table "upcTable" is not given in the script $('#myTable').dataTable();

> Please replace #myTable with #upcTable.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#upcTable').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",    
    "responsive": true
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi I fixed that code,still I'm unable to apply styling

Comment: can u provide a fiddle of what u have done till now..?

Comment: Add all the datatables and bootstrap related js and css in external resources for this to work.

Comment: I think i added all files